# Should I say "I don't know nothing" or "I know nothing"?

Tags: negative-concord

Which of the following is correct?

> "I don't know nothing"

or

> "I know nothing"?

The context:

> Question: Do you know who told him this thing?
>
> Answer: No, I don't know nothing about that.

Comment: First means that he knows at least something. Double negative is used here. In the latter sentence, the person know nothing. Second one is correct.

Comment: Correction: *knows